# show two blocks of one row

Tags: html, css

I want to show two blocks of one row and these blocks of varying heights.

Now I'm using `float: left` and get a space (yellow shows the Screenshot):

[image: screenshot 1]

How to avoid a space?

CSS:

```
.one{
    float: left;
    border:1px solid #C11A1A;
    width: 50px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="width: 110px;">
<div class="one" style="height:50px;">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="one">           
        2
    </div>
    <div class="one" style="height:70px;">
        3
    </div>
    <div class="one">
        4
    </div>
    <div class="one" style="height:50px;">
        5
    </div>
    <div class="one">
        6
    </div>
    <div class="one">
        7
    </div>
</div>
```

With two div, I get this variant:

[image: screenshot 2]

I want to get the same columns height (As far as possible), block sizes vary depending on the text.

Comment: Why are you using divs for tabular data?

Comment: You now get exactly what you said: each row contains two blocks. If you want to make two columns without spaces between blocks then make two `div`s for columns and fill them with blocks.

Comment: Here a jsfiddle for all to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/F7saH/

Comment: Do you mean something like Facebook timeline? :)

Comment: I would suggest to use [this plugin](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/setting_equal_heights_with_jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set and `float:left` and set an span with an `auto:width` arround your "blocks"